# Reading the content from 0000:FFFF to AX register may change CS:IP to F000:E9DF

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, real-mode

I want to read the word at memory address 0000:FFFF, but when I debug my program:

```
org  0x7C00
mov  ax, 0x0000
mov  ds, ax
mov  ax, [0xFFFF]
```

executing the last instruction `mov  ax, [0xFFFF]`, will change CS:IP to F000:E9DF. So strange...

Comment: How are you single-stepping this, and in what debugger?  And in what x86 simulator / emulator?  Is it possible that garbage bytes in memory executed after that, and included a far `jmp`?  Oh, or did a 2-byte access at `0xFFFF` cause a fault for exceeding the 64k segment limit, and `f000:e9df` came from the IDT?

Comment: Probably because the garbage in memory that follows your last instruction is interpreted as instructions and results in strange behavior. Use halt to stop the CPU execution.

Comment: can you add `jmp $` to create infinite cycle and test after that? The CPU will otherwise wander into the memory executing everything it finds there... unless you are single-stepping it in debugger, then you should get the control right after the `mov ax,...`.

Comment: I use bochs as simulator. I try to add `jmp $` after `mov ax, [0xFFFF]`, but when `mov ax, [0xFFFF]` executed, CS:IP still change to F000:E9DF, and `jmp $` doesn't run...

Comment: While this is itself interesting, to solve your actual problem of reading a byte make sure you read just a single byte e.g. use `al` or `movzx ax`.

Comment: Reading a WORD at the end of a segment will cause a #GP (yes, even in real mode).

Comment: @Jester Yeah! It works! But why I can't read word?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm a beginner, can you tell me what is GP? Thanks.

Comment: `#GP` is usual notation for General Protection Fault Exception. You can't read a word because address `0xFFFF` is the last byte in the segment, There is no other byte after it which would be needed for a word.

Comment: @Jester Ok, Thank you ^_^